# Is there any way to give a format to arithmetic computations in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, formatter, arithmetic-expressions

i want to define something similar to a computation method:

> NSString *format = @"%d + 1";

In my code i want to do something like:

> int computedNumber = sum(format,5) => the result should be 6.

could you give some suggestions?
thank you

EDIT:
or something similar to:
NSNumber *no = [NSNumber numberWithFormat:format,5];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not normally possible, however there have been written parsers for this specific tasks, to mention [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) by SO user [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong).

But for what task do you really need this? You have the `+` operator, and then you perform the `sum` function? Couldn't you simply parse the number at the end of the format, then perform the operation you'd like?

Comment: i hoped that iOS has a magic piece of code that could do something similar. i'll parse the string and perform the specified operation. but it would have been cool to do something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Macro` can be an alternative solution to your problem. You can define a `macro` like the following,

```
#define INC(a) (a + 1)
```

Here, **INC** and **a** are user-defined. You can give them any name you want. Compiler will substitute **(a + 1)** in your code, where ever you call **INC(a)**. For example, consider the following,

```
int computedNumber = INC(5);
```

After the compilation the code will be,

```
int computedNumber = (5 + 1); // the result during the execution is 6.
```